# Hidden class css

Tags: javascript, html, hidden

I try to create project on frontendMentor and have an issue. When i complete the form and click button element form doesnt hide. There are many new lines and this element is on the bottom. What is the problem?
Code:

```js
const cardName = document.querySelector('.name');
const cardNumber = document.querySelector('.number');
const cardMonth = document.querySelector('.month');
const cardYear = document.querySelector('.year');
const cardCode = document.querySelector('.code');
const btn = document.querySelector('.button');
const resultName = document.querySelector('.card__name');
const resultNumber = document.querySelector('.header__cards-number');
const resultExpiry = document.querySelector('.card__expiry');
const resultCvv = document.querySelector('.header__cvv');
const summary = document.querySelector('.summary');
const form = document.querySelector('.form');
// const resultDate = document.querySelector();
btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    resultName.innerHTML = cardName.value;
    resultNumber.innerHTML = cardNumber.value;
    resultExpiry.innerHTML = `${cardMonth.value}/${cardYear.value}`;
    resultCvv.innerHTML = cardCode.value;
    summary.classList.remove('hidden');
    form.classList.add('hidden');
});
```

```css
$white: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
$lightGrayishViolet: hsl(270, 3%, 87%);
$darkGrayishViolet: hsl(279, 6%, 55%);
$veryDarkViolet: hsl(278, 68%, 11%);
$red: hsl(0, 100%, 66%);
$linearGradient: hsl(249, 99%, 64%) to hsl(278, 94%, 30%);

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Space Grotesk', sans-serif;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 375px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.header {
    flex-basis: 35%;
    background-image: url('../images/bg-main-mobile.png');
    &__card {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 300px;
        height: 150px;

        border-radius: 0.5em;
    }

    &__cards {
        &-back {
            position: relative;
            margin-top: 1.5em;
            margin-left: 3em;
            background-color: $white;
        }
        &-front {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            position: absolute;
            background-image: url('../images/bg-card-front.png');
            color: $white;
            top: 117px;
            left: 15px;

            z-index: 10;
            overflow: hidden;
            padding: 1em 1em;
        }
        &-logo {
            flex-basis: 50%;
            width: 100%;

            svg {
                text-align-last: left;
                margin-left: -1em;
                transform: scale(0.5);
            }
        }
        &-number {
            flex-basis: 20%;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
        }
        &-details {
            width: 100%;
            flex-basis: 30%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: flex-end;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 0.7em;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
    }

    &__magneticbar {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 30px;
        margin-top: 1em;
        background-color: #333;
    }
    &__cvv {
        width: 80%;
        height: 30px;
        text-align: right;
        padding-right: 1em;
        background-color: $lightGrayishViolet;
        line-height: 30px;
        border-radius: 0.2em;
        color: $white;
        font-size: 0.7em;
        color: $white;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
    }

    .content {
        flex-basis: 65%;
    }
}

.content {
    flex-basis: 65%;
    padding: 1em;

    .description {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        font-size: 0.7em;
        text-align: left;
        color: $veryDarkViolet;
        margin-bottom: 0.3em;
    }
    .form {
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        align-items: center;
        text-align: center;

        &__item {
            width: 100%;
            margin-bottom: 0.5em;
            input {
                width: 100%;
                height: 3em;
                border-radius: 0.3em;
                border: 1px solid $lightGrayishViolet;
            }
            input::placeholder {
                font-size: 1.3em;
                color: $lightGrayishViolet;
            }
        }

        &__row {
            display: flex;

            .form__item {
                input {
                    width: 23%;
                    text-align: center;
                }
                .code {
                    width: 50%;
                }
                span {
                    margin-left: 2em;
                }
            }
        }
        &__button {
            width: 100%;
            height: 3em;
            margin-top: 1em;
            margin-bottom: 2em;
            line-height: 3em;
            background-color: $veryDarkViolet;
            color: $white;
            border-radius: 0.5em;
        }
    }
}

.summary {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    &__icon {
        margin: 2em 0;
    }
    &__text {
        h1 {
            text-transform: uppercase;
            letter-spacing: 3px;
        }
        p {
            color: $darkGrayishViolet;
            margin: 1em 0;
        }
    }
    &__button {
        margin-top: 2em;
        background-color: lime;
    }
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

        <link
            rel="icon"
            type="image/png"
            sizes="32x32"
            href="./images/favicon-32x32.png"
        />

        <title>Frontend Mentor | Interactive card details form</title>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
        <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Space+Grotesk:wght@500&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <div class="header__cards">
                <div class="header__card header__cards-back">
                    <div class="header__magneticbar"></div>
                    <div class="header__cvv">000</div>
                </div>
                <div class="header__card header__cards-front">
                    <div class="header__cards-logo">
                        <svg
                            width="84"
                            height="47"
                            fill="none"
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                        >
                            <ellipse
                                cx="23.478"
                                cy="23.5"
                                rx="23.478"
                                ry="23.5"
                                fill="#fff"
                            />
                            <path
                                d="M83.5 23.5c0 5.565-4.507 10.075-10.065 10.075-5.559 0-10.065-4.51-10.065-10.075 0-5.565 4.506-10.075 10.065-10.075 5.558 0 10.065 4.51 10.065 10.075Z"
                                stroke="#fff"
                            />
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                    <div class="header__cards-number">0000 0000 0000 0000</div>
                    <div class="header__cards-details">
                        <div class="card__name">Jane Appleseed</div>
                        <div class="card__expiry">00/00</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="summary hidden">
                <div class="summary__icon">
                    <svg
                        width="80"
                        height="80"
                        fill="none"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    >
                        <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="40" fill="url(#a)" />
                        <path
                            d="M28 39.92 36.08 48l16-16"
                            stroke="#fff"
                            stroke-width="3"
                        />
                        <defs>
                            <linearGradient
                                id="a"
                                x1="-23.014"
                                y1="11.507"
                                x2="0"
                                y2="91.507"
                                gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                            >
                                <stop stop-color="#6348FE" />
                                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#610595" />
                            </linearGradient>
                        </defs>
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="summary__text">
                    <h1>Thank you!</h1>
                    <p>We've added your card details</p>
                </div>
                <div class="form__button summary__button">Continue</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form">
                <div class="form__item">
                    <div class="description">Cardholder Name</div>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="name"
                        id="name"
                        class="name"
                        placeholder=" e.g. Jane Appleseed"
                    />
                </div>
                <div class="form__item">
                    <div class="description">Card Number</div>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="number"
                        id="number"
                        class="number"
                        placeholder="e.g. 1234 5678 9123 0000"
                        maxlength="19"
                    />
                </div>
                <div class="form__row">
                    <div class="form__item">
                        <div class="description">
                            Exp. Date (MM/YY)<span>CVC</span>
                        </div>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="month"
                            id="month"
                            class="month"
                            placeholder="MM"
                            maxlength="2"
                            minlength="2"
                        />
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="year"
                            id="year"
                            class="year"
                            placeholder="YY"
                            maxlength="2"
                            minlength="2"
                        />
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="code"
                            id="code"
                            class="code"
                            placeholder="e.g. 123"
                            minlength="3"
                            maxlength="3"
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form__button button">Confirm</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="./script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I add some images too[image][image]

I know that my code is bad but i dont use any tutorials and hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).
In your SASS(?) your `.form` is nested inside `.content` which when compiled looks something like this `.content .form { ...` and this has higher specificity than `.hidden`, so make it more specific to override or use `!important`:

```css
.content .form {
  display: flex;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

/* More specific */
.content .form.super-hidden {
  display: none;
}

/* Using !important */
.important-hidden {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="form">I am visible to the world</div>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div class="content">
  <div class="form hidden">Why am i not hidden?</div>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div class="content">
  <div class="form super-hidden">I am definitely hidden</div>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div class="content">
  <div class="form important-hidden">I am definitely hidden</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It took me some time to do this, but you can also try this. Maybe it helps.

```js
const confButton = document.getElementById("confButton");
const actSect = document.getElementById("active");
const hidSect = document.getElementById("hidden");

confButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  actSect.classList.remove("active");
  actSect.classList.add("hidden");

  hidSect.classList.remove("hidden");
  hidSect.classList.add("active");

});
```

```css
:root {
  --white:              hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  --lightGrayishViolet: hsl(270, 3%, 87%);
  --darkGrayishViolet:  hsl(279, 6%, 55%);
  --veryDarkViolet:     hsl(278, 68%, 11%);
  --red:                hsl(0, 100%, 66%);
  --linearGradient:     hsl(249, 99%, 64%) to hsl(278, 94%, 30%);
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  display:         flex;
  flex-direction:  column;
  align-items:     center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding:         1rem;
  height:          100vh;
  width:           100%;
}

body {
  font-size:       18px;
  font-family:     "Space Grotesk", sans-serif;
  height:          100vh;
  width:           100%;
  max-width:       375px;
  display:         flex;
  flex-direction:  column;
  font-weight:     500;
}

.header__card {
  display:         flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:     center;
  width:           300px;
  height:          150px;
  border-radius:   0.5em;
}

.header__cards-back {
  position:          relative;
  margin-top:        1.5em;
  margin-left:       3em;
  background-color:  var(--white);
}

.header__cards-front {
  display:             flex;
  flex-direction:      column;
  position:            absolute;
  background:          rgb(137, 119, 241);
  background:          linear-gradient( 124deg, rgba(137, 119, 241, 1) 0%, rgba(116, 81, 245, 1) 16%, rgba(116, 55, 231, 1) 39%, rgba(194, 73, 219, 1) 64%, rgba(179, 119, 176, 1) 78%, rgba(108, 144, 220, 1) 100%);
  color:              var(--white);
  top:                117px;
  left:               15px;
  z-index:            10;
  overflow:           hidden;
  padding:            1em 1em;
}

.header__cards-logo {
  flex-basis:         50%;
  width:              100%;
}

.header__cards-logo svg {
  text-align-last:    left;
  margin-left:        -1em;
  transform:          scale(0.5);
}

.header__cards-number {
  flex-basis:         20%;
  width:              100%;
  text-align:         center;
  letter-spacing:     2px;
}

.header { 
  flex-basis:         35%;
  padding:            .5rem;
  background:         rgb(35, 14, 55);
  background:         linear-gradient( 144deg, rgba(35, 14, 55, 1) 0%, rgba(69, 27, 62, 1) 62%, rgba(33, 8, 46, 1) 100%);
}

.header__cards-details {
  width:               100%;
  flex-basis:          30%;
  display:             flex;
  justify-content:     space-between;
  align-items:         flex-end;
  text-align:          center;
  font-size:           0.7em;
  letter-spacing:      2px;
  text-transform:      uppercase;
}

.header__magneticbar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 1em;
  background-color: #333;
}

.header__cvv {
  width: 80%;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 1em;
  background-color: var(--lightGrayishViolet);
  line-height: 30px;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  color: var(--white);
  font-size: 0.7em;
  color: var(--white);
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.content {
  flex-basis: 65%;
}

.description {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  text-align: left;
  color: var(--veryDarkViolet);
  margin-bottom: 0.3em;
}

.form__item {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.form__item input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3em;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  border: 1px solid var(--lightGrayishViolet);
}

.form__item input::placeholder {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: var(--lightGrayishViolet);
}

.form__item input {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.form__row .form__item input {
  width: 23%;
}

.form__item .code {
  width: 50%;
}

.form__item span {
  margin-left: 2em;
}

.form__button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3em;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  line-height: 3em;
  background-color: var(--veryDarkViolet);
  color: var(--white);
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}

.form {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  flex-basis: 65%;
  padding: 1em;
}

.summery__text h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.summery__text p {
  color: var(--darkGrayishViolet);
  margin: 1em 0;
}

.summery__icon {
  margin: 2em 0;
}

.summery__button {
  margin-top: 2em;
  background-color: lime;
}

.summary {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section id="active">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header__cards">
      <div class="header__card header__cards-back">
        <div class="header__magneticbar"></div>
        <div class="header__cvv">000</div>
      </div>
      <div class="header__card header__cards-front">
        <div class="header__cards-logo">
          <svg width="84" height="47" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <ellipse
                  cx="23.478"
                  cy="23.5"
                  rx="23.478"
                  ry="23.5"
                  fill="#fff"
                />
                <path
                  d="M83.5 23.5c0 5.565-4.507 10.075-10.065 10.075-5.559 0-10.065-4.51-10.065-10.075 0-5.565 4.506-10.075 10.065-10.075 5.558 0 10.065 4.51 10.065 10.075Z"
                  stroke="#fff"
                />
              </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="header__cards-number">0000 0000 0000 0000</div>
        <div class="header__cards-details">
          <div class="card__name">Jane Appleseed</div>
          <div class="card__expiry">00/00</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="summary hidden">
      <div class="summary__icon">
        <svg width="80" height="80" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="40" fill="url(#a)" />
              <path
                d="M28 39.92 36.08 48l16-16"
                stroke="#fff"
                stroke-width="3"
              />
              <defs>
                <linearGradient
                  id="a"
                  x1="-23.014"
                  y1="11.507"
                  x2="0"
                  y2="91.507"
                  gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                >
                  <stop stop-color="#6348FE" />
                  <stop offset="1" stop-color="#610595" />
                </linearGradient>
              </defs>
            </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="summary__text">
        <h1>Thank you!</h1>
        <p>We've added your card details</p>
      </div>
      <div class="form__button summary__button">Continue</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form">
      <div class="form__item">
        <div class="description">Cardholder Name</div>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="name" placeholder=" e.g. Jane Appleseed" />
      </div>
      <div class="form__item">
        <div class="description">Card Number</div>
        <input type="text" name="number" id="number" class="number" placeholder="e.g. 1234 5678 9123 0000" maxlength="19" />
      </div>
      <div class="form__row">
        <div class="form__item">
          <div class="description">Exp. Date (MM/YY)<span>CVC</span></div>
          <input type="text" name="month" id="month" class="month" placeholder="MM" maxlength="2" minlength="2" />
          <input type="text" name="year" id="year" class="year" placeholder="YY" maxlength="2" minlength="2" />
          <input type="text" name="code" id="code" class="code" placeholder="e.g. 123" minlength="3" maxlength="3" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form__button button " id="confButton">Confirm</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="hidden" class="hidden">Thank you</section>
```